# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined when attempting to select root HTML tag

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm attempting to add variables to the HTML tag in angular dynamically from an API - I can get static variables to work but when I try to get them from the API I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

In my app.component.ts file I have the following code on Init:

```
el: ElementRef; // Defined in AppCompoent Class


// Get brandColours from API...

// Set variables
const appHtmlElement = (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-additional-accent', brandColours?.additionalAccent);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-dark-highlight', brandColours?.darkHighlight);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-input-accent', brandColours?.inputAccent);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-light-highlight', brandColours?.lightHighlight);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-primary', brandColours?.primary);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-secondary', brandColours?.secondary);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-tertiary', brandColours?.tertiary);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-text-dark', brandColours?.textDark);
appHtmlElement.style.setProperty('--color-text-light', brandColours?.textLight);
```

And in styles CSS I have some defaults:

```
:root {
    --color-additional-accent: #C7D300;
    --color-dark-highlight: #945400;
    --color-input-accent: #FFA731; 
    --color-light-highlight: #FFB95D;
    --color-primary: #000000; 
    --color-secondary: #fad900;
    --color-tertiary: #018aa5; 
    --color-text-dark: #7d7d7d; 
    --color-text-light: #bbc2b4; 
}
```

I get the defaults working no worries but they're not replaced with the hex values from the API - I've checked the values returned from the API and they're a-ok so it's not the values themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always safer to implement changes to elements in the ngAfterViewInit() method.

That should fix it as per the angular documentation on https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview